# change user's privileges on mysql using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Hi I need to create an user in mysql using sqlalchemy: I am able to check the existence of the user before creating it and create it if it does not exist but when i try to gran t all the privileges on the db I get  this error
    e`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
thos are the instructions that  I use:`

self.engine.execute("CREATE USER 'metmi' IDENTIFIED BY  'metmi'")`

and

```
`self.engine.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO metmi@'\%' IDENTIFIED BY  'metmi'")`
```

if I use the same instruction on phpMyadmin or on the mysql prompt it works, so I am really puzzled, do not know what is wrong;
can somebody tell me what is my error?
thankls in advance

Comment: Try using "%%" for a literal "%".

Answer (score 0):

I Solved I had tocreate the same user on localhost, for  the internal process of Mysql